# get the ip address from a remote client: remote_endpoint: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: c++, sockets, ip, client, boost-asio

does anyone know how to get the ip address of a remote client from a socket 
i have tried this function : 
i have tried to use this function :

```
std::string s =socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
```

but i always get the following error even if i can ping from and to the client :
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
  what():  remote_endpoint: Transport endpoint is not connected
^[[AAbandon (core dumped)

is there any way to retrieve the ip address of the sender (ps :want to use it for a checkup before sending data)

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service);
socket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
socket.bind(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(
boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(),port));

std::cout << "Ready to receive" << std::endl;

//information about where the packets come from
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender;
/////retrieve ip
std::string s =socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string(); 
std::cout << "The client's ip is:" << s << std::endl;
```

Comment: Use [receive_from](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/receive_from.html). When you get data, check `sender_endpoint`, it will be filled by sender ip.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct sockaddr_in sAddr;
socklen_t sLen = sizeof sAddr;
[your socket] = accept([socket to listen], (struct sockaddr *) &sAddr, &sLen);

printf("%s",inet_ntoa(sAddr.sin_addr));
```

Replace `your socket` and `socket to listen` with yours'.

Comment: This answer doesn't use the language or any of the libraries used by OP. It also doesn't address the special considerations surrounding UDP, because that's a connectionless protocol and you do need other provisions to get the peer address with a datagram received. Finally, you are using printf to print the address that accept bound to (that's not the sender), regardless of the fact that this does not result in the endpoint in usable form. @rafix07' comment has the correct approach and predates this answer.